# "public" val constructor parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

What is wrong with this declaration? Why is `public` not allowed in given code?

```
class Alpha( public val a:Int,public val b:Int)
```

It might seem a silly question, but is this due to encapsulation?

Comment: Because `public` is not a keyword at all in Scala. Things are `public` by default. (This is different from Java!).

Comment: I thought it is there . Since it is in Java . I thougt it would be there .thanks

Comment: Scala is not Java, just because something exists in Java doesn't mean that it exists in Scala too. I wrote a blogpost about Scala access modifiers: [Scala access modifiers and qualifiers in detail](http://www.jesperdj.com/2016/01/08/scala-access-modifiers-and-qualifiers-in-detail/)

Comment: Yes I found your blog http://www.jesperdj.com/2016/01/08/scala-access-modifiers-and-qualifiers-in-detail/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `public` keyword in Scala. The default Access modifier in Scala is public. In your case, if you remove `public` from your constructor signature, it will make the parameters public.

```
//Public 
class Alpha(val a: Int, val b: Int){}

//Private 
class Alpha(private val a: Int, private val b: Int){}
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, compare `class C(x: Int)` and `class C(val x: Int)`. Only `val`s and `var`s are public by default. The former always defines a private field.

Comment: To be precise, the former `class C(x: Int)` doesn't define a private field; it defines a constructor arg, which is only accessible to the current instance.